# Using Rails optimistic locking on real-time editor data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimistic-locking

I'm working with a real-time editor (https://beefree.io/) in my Rails app. Multiple users can edit a document and it autosaves every 10 seconds, returning a JSON object representing the document along with a version number that increments with every change. The JSON object is being saved to a table associated with a Document model.

I'm curious if optimistic locking could be used to prevent user's old changes from overwriting newer changes in the case that a save request doesn't complete in time. The idea would be to use the version number that the editor provides, and use it within the `lock_version` column. Can I pass an arbitrary value to lock_version like that? Or is the database meant to increment the value itself?

Another issue I have is that I'm saving to a table that has other columns that I don't want to be locked by this `lock_version` attribute. Can I specifically lock the real-time data column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm curious if optimistic locking could be used to prevent user's old changes from overwriting newer changes in the case that a save request doesn't complete in time. The idea would be to use the version number that the editor provides, and use it within the lock_version column. Can I pass an arbitrary value to lock_version like that? Or is the database meant to increment the value itself?

With Rails' built-in optimistic locking, Active Record (and not your code) is supposed to be responsible for incrementing lock_version. You might be able to pass in your own lock_version with an update, but Rails will still auto-increment it with any other updates to the model. But, given the second part of your question...

> Another issue I have is that I'm saving to a table that has other columns that I don't want to be locked by this lock_version attribute. Can I specifically lock the real-time data column?

Locking only for updates to certain columns is not a feature Rails currently supports, though there might be a gem or monkey-patch out there you could accomplish it with. However, given this as well as your need for a custom version number, it would probably be easiest just to implement optimistic locking yourself for just this update:

```rb
# last version is what the editor thinks is the last saved version
# new version is the new version provided by the editor
# this update will only succeed if the document still has version=last_version

Document.where(id: document.id, version: last_version)
        .update_all(version: new_version, text: new_text)
```

I do want to point out that, while this will prevent out-of-order changes, collaborative editing (two or more people editing the same doc in real time) is still not going to be fully functional. To get a real collaborative editor, you'll need to implement an solution based on either [OT (operational transform)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation) or [CRDT (conflict-free replicated data type)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-free_replicated_data_type). See also:

- https://www.aha.io/engineering/articles/how-to-build-collaborative-text-editor-rails
- https://github.com/benaubin/rails-collab

Comment: Thanks, that clarified my question about trying to use the editor's version parameter. Sounds like I'm better off implementing that myself.

I should have clarified, I'm not building the real-time editor, I'm using BEE (updated the question). The BEE editor handles the collaborative changes, syncing each session, but I need to handle saving to our database. Right now, a PUT request is sent every few seconds in each session, so we have multiple PUT requests coming through and I need to save the most recent, based on the version number.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. Are the version numbers always increasing? You could make it a little simpler and allow the update only if the new version is more recent: `Document.where(id: document.id).where("version < ?", new_version).update_all(version: new_version, text: new_text)` (this could happen in a DB trigger, too).

Comment: Yes, always increasing. I thought I'd have to do something more like that, incase one of the requests doesn't get through for some reason, causing a gap in `last_version`s.
Going to give this a try. Thanks for the help.